# Creating a Buzzer System using python

Tags: python, pygame, keydown

We are having a holiday party at work, and are trying to set up a Family Feud game. With that, I'm trying to program a buzzer system. I am very new to pygame so maybe there is a better approach to what I'm trying to do.

I've written the following code which works to some degree. Right now, it recognizes the button and displays the picture as it should; however, it is recognizing all button presses where I only want it to recognize the first until after it is reset. For example, the left side buzzes in first, I want their picture to be displayed - then if the right team buzzes in after, I want that button to be ignored. Then if a third (reset) button is pushed, it resets back to the beginning to begin tracking for the first button pushed again. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import pygame
import pdcurses
#import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import image
import time
import clock
from pygame import mixer
from pygame.locals import *

displayWidth = 1600
displayHeight = 1200

pygame.init()
#mixer.init()
#pygame.display.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((displayWidth, displayHeight))
pygame.display.set_caption('Family Feud')
pygame.display.update()

def reset():
    global screen
    kids = pygame.image.load("kids.jpg")
    screen.blit(kids, (0,0))
    pygame.display.update()


gameExit = False
while not gameExit:

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == K_LEFT:
            leftBuzzer = pygame.image.load("ice cream.jpg")
            screen.blit(leftBuzzer,(0,0))
            pygame.display.update()


        if event.key == K_RIGHT:
            rightBuzzer = pygame.image.load("snowman.jpg")
            screen.blit(rightBuzzer,(0,0))
            pygame.display.update()


        if event.key == K_q:
            pygame.quit()


        if event.key == K_r:
            reset()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add an `alreadyPressed` boolean and for each buzzer press have an `if` statement check `alreadyPressed` before displaying anything.

Comment: Could you help with what that would look like - Would I be somehow testing if event.type - keydown already occurred with each? Also, if so, how would I then get it to reset back to the beginning screen to monitor again for the next question?

Comment: Something like          if event.key == K_q and isPressed = false:      That way even if the button is pressed nothing will happen (as long is you have something in your button press code to set isPressed to true.

Comment: I made some slight changes to the reset option and it is working as it should. Thank you so much!